# Accessing view of a recycler view inside an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a simple layout consisting of recycler view with edit texts in it and a button after the recycler view.

Whenever user presses a button, I want to check whether all edit text is filled or not, If its not filled then I want to show a toast message to user telling its empty

Comment: Instead of trying to access views inside your activity whenever button is clicked you can call a method inside your Adapter that is responsible for checking the edittext value and showing toast message (It's not good to access views in activity, it's adapter's job to handle all of it's views)

Answer (score 0):

Get all the children of the recyclerview (the edittexts), read their data and check if its empty

```
  boolean isEmpty = false;
  RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
  for (int x=0;x<recyclerView.getChildCount();x++) {
       EditText et = (EditText) recyclerView.getChildAt(x);
       if (!et.getText().toString().equals(""));
       {
           isEmpty=true;
       }
   }

   //use isEmpty
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have items linked to each row of recycler view. You can maintain a flag or check if all items.editext has value on button click.  Ideally you shouldnt use recyclerview with edit box unless you have such specific requirement.
You can use data binding inside each row of recycler view and from the viewmodel you will get details of whether all edit boxes have values.

Answer (score 0):

Your recycler view adapter should have a list of data objects, in your case (at least) a list of Strings. This list should be updated once you edit one of the EditTexts.

When pressing the button you should check if the data list from the adapter has any empty strings.

Checking for views won't help you because if you have a recycler view with 100 items you will only be able to check the visible items plus a few extra. These views get recycled all the time to save memory (hence the name RecyclerView).

So long story-short, don't rely on your UI to make this type of check. Rely on the underlying data instead.

Comment: But how can I get the reference to the view(edittext) to check if its empty or not?

Comment: You don't check if the EditText is empty. You check if the data at that position is empty. When you change the text from one of your EditTexts you save the contents to the data array at the correct position. You then check for an empty string not for the contents of the EditText.

Comment: you can use interfaces for this purpose